# Changing text of UIButton titleLabel during alpha is 0.0f and avoid animation of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton, beginanimations

Im fading my `UIButton.titleLabel` in/out a few times like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOutText" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    button.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];

button.titleLabel.text = @"Changed text";

[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInText" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    button.titleLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The thing is that i want to change the text during the time when it is hidden (alpha is 0.0f).
But when I fade the text back in, the text is animated aswell. Its appearing/moving in from the right of the label.

Is there a way to avoid that the text is being animated?

The fade in and the fade out are called after each other using `NSTimer`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a separate code section for the text change seems to remove the animation of the text.

This how i solved it, maybe there are better solutions?

```
-(void)hideText{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOutText" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        button.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(setText)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)setText{
    [button setTitle:@"changedText" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(showText)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
}
-(void)showText{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInText" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        button.titleLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: the problem is that new title sets different frame, and frame animation is applied to the label itself. Your workaround solves this problem because animation's context is separated and performed in a sequence

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             button.titleLabel.alpha:0.0f;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                              button.titleLabel.text = @"Changed text";
                         }
];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             button.titleLabel.alpha:1.0f;
                         }
];
```